# Xcode unable to run the sample project on mac OSX 10.9.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I build the sample project and i try to run the app but Xcode unable to run the app.The Xcode gets the hang and not responding.I quit the Xcode and even I restart the system too but not helpful. Please any help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to delete project.xcworkspace in package content of your .xcodeproj file

Comment: Thanks for your post but I updated to XCode6.1.1 its working fine.But,may I know reason of deleting the project.xcworkspace?

Comment: @sunny It will reset the project settings, breakpoints, state etc.